# How do I remove teak oil from a granite kitchen counter top?

Tags: repair

I mistakenly rubbed teak oil on my granite counter top. How do I remove it without damaging it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely acetone. You can buy acetone at any hardware store. Get an ace bandage and soak the acetone in a bowl in the sink. Do not ring it out, and place it over the stain spreading it out to completely cover the stain. Pull saran wrap over the gauze with plenty extra to secure the gauze so the acetone will not evaporate. Leave it on for a couple days. Easy and it works. You can use anything that absorbs from gauze to a old cotton shirt. Acetone will evaporate fast so that is why you cover it with the saran.

Answer (score 0):

[Acetone](http://www.marble-institute.com/consumers/stains/) seems to be what many people recommend.